# Allow page parameter in query string of a wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a site and need to keep the page parameter in the query string on redirect. Wordpress strips page out. I cannot change the parameter name because a script I have no control over depends on that name. Is there a way to stop wordpress from filtering/stripping that parameter from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do was add a page outside the wp install with the ep header and footer